# Eclipse can't create Groovy class in 4.3.2

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin, groovy-eclipse

I just installed Eclipse 4.3.2 (EE) and then immediately installed the Groovy plugin for it (from [this link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Install+Groovy-Eclipse+Plugin) - I used `http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.2/` as the plugin site).

Upon restarting Eclipse I created a new Groovy Project, and then added a new package (`com.me.myapp`) and then tried to add a new Groovy class to this package.

This prompted Eclipse to open a `Create new Groovy Class` dialog. I added a name for my class (`ExampleGroovy`) and then clicked "Finish" to create the class.

Upon doing this I am getting the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyApp'.
    org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory
```

Have I configured Groovy incorrectly, or did the makers of the Groovy-Eclipse plugin publish something that just doesn't work?

Comment: Same as [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1676)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the update site URL for Kepler you used is incorrect. It should be http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3 probably.

I personally always use this update site http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3 and pick Groovy Eclipse there.
What's you JDK version?

Comment: This is not an answer. Gain reputation and use comments.